# Location-based app works fine in simulator, hangs on the device

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I have developped a location based iphone application which works perfectly in emulators, but when I make the IPA file with my device UDID and install it on that specific device it only shows the splash screen and then stop working, giving the following log:

```
12/3/12 10:25:39.000 PM kernel: IsPacketAllowedForFlow:IPAFF: Not enough tokens in queue 0 with head size 4216 Available 3334
12/3/12 10:25:39.000 PM kernel: CheckAndSendPacketFromIndex: No space pended

[message repeated many times]

12/3/12 10:25:40.000 PM kernel: 12000 Available 8486
```

the log file is long enough that I couldn't post it here, but here is another part of that file where I can see this also:

```
12/3/12 10:54:16.000 PM kernel: TransmitPacketsTask:Acquired Terminate semaphore with status = 0
12/3/12 10:54:16.000 PM kernel: /Users/rdd2/Project/Banglalion/mac/bcsRelease/Rel-6.1.3.4/Driver/BeceemAppleWiMAXAdapter/Sources/BeceemAppleWiMAXAdapter.cpp:getMaxPacketSize:2209:returning max size =7ee ===>
12/3/12 10:54:16.000 PM kernel: initialPowerStateForDomainState===> powerStateWillChangeTo():  
12/3/12 10:54:16.000 PM kernel:  
12/3/12 10:54:16.000 PM kernel: createNetworkInterface: <=====
12/3/12 10:54:16.000 PM kernel: initForPM: =====>
12/3/12 10:54:16.000 PM kernel: initForPM: <=====
12/3/12 10:54:16.000 PM kernel: ===> setPowerState() powerStateOrdinal : 0x1  
12/3/12 10:54:16.000 PM kernel:  
12/3/12 10:54:16.000 PM kernel: Got sleep/wake notice.  Message type was e0000340
12/3/12 10:54:16.000 PM kernel: ===> powerStateDidChangeTo():
```

I am totally stuck here for 6-7 days, and I have no idea what is wrong.

Comment: Does the app crashes every time or does it remain stuck on splash screen?

Comment: when i click on that icon it just shows the splash screen and get vanishes, nothing remains visible

Comment: You said you are making an .ipa file. How exactly are you generating it?

Comment: I have followed the instruction from this link:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/YourFirstAppStoreSubmission/TestYourApponManyDevicesandiOSVersions/TestYourApponManyDevicesandiOSVersions.html

but its the first time I have made ipa, how can I recognise if I did any wrong?

Comment: Before moving onto that lets check one more thing. Try installing your app in device using Xcode in Distribution mode. let me know what happens

Comment: can you refer me a link or tutorial on how to do this? I am new in this sector

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20559/discussion-between-reyjohn-and-evol-gate)